# Browser setting or extension to disable URL Rewriting

Tags: browser, extension, url-rewriting

Sometimes I browse some websites, they had ads on their page, it is fine by me. But the ads rewrites URL so I can't go back to the page I browsed anymore, but go back to the page before instead. When I get back to the page, the rewriting happens again. This is sooooo annoying.

Anyway to disable URL Rewriting on a browser? Any browser is okey. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you supply us an example page or site that currently does this?

Comment: @leeharvey1 sample https://tsukimichimanga.com/ . In our country, it replaced URL to an electronic commerce page (like Amazon)

Comment: If I allow both Trackers and Ads in Vivaldi, and disable my DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension, then I can see the problem you describe.  I might suggest visiting content (eg, robots.txt) on each ad and tracker domain, then go into Site Settings, and block Notifications, JavaScript, Images, Pop-ups and redirects, Intrusive ads, etc. for those domains.  FYI, I used Vivaldi and DuckDuckGo Privacy Extension to show me these Ad and Tracker domains...

Comment: For your sample site, ads and trackers seem to originate from these domains: api.purpleads.io
cdn.purpleads.io, cdn.onesignal.com, onesignal.com, doubleclick.net, googleads.g.doubleclick.net, static.doubleclick.com, googlesyndication.com, pagead2.googlesyndication.com, google-analytics.com, www.google-analytics.com, roommateskinner.com, services.vlitag.com, silentinevitable.com, and sync.adkernel.com.